# Tinymce5 mobile reply background colour issue

Tags: javascript, tinymce, yetanotherforum, yaf

I am using tinymce5 with yet another forums.  In mobile view the background is black I want it to be white but I am unsure as to what I need to change to get a white background.

In the reply box on clicking the edit image it's adding inline styles to the HTML tag and body tags. So I cannot just add class to init of tinymce and add styles to my style sheet for that class as the inline styles are set to !important.

Is there config setting somewhere I need to tweak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of TinyMCE 5 are you using? We fixed an issue with the mobile background colour in 5.0.2:

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/5.0.2/changelog.txt#L14

Comment: It's on 5.0.0-1

Comment: do you happen to know the commit that fixed that issue?

Comment: Yup: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/commit/3d40eaa6c03412707544054e6c62e9a6bc24ee3d We had a problem with 5.0.0 where we didn't realise iframe elements were transparent by default.

Comment: I don’t think it solve the problem, as the inline styles have !important. They will still overwrite any other css? Also this commit refers to ios we are seeing this on android as well.

There must be something additional in js?

Comment: Oh so you're not the one integrating TinyMCE? You probably need to ask the forum developers then.

Comment: ok managed to get to fix this, from the tinymce source got the mobile theme and updated the theme.less file .tinymce-mobile-outer-container {
    .tinymce-mobile-editor-socket iframe {
      background-color: #FFF;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }